# Multiple files download on one progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms

I have sometimes 1, sometimes 4-5 to download. 
And I don't want progress bar to reset on 0 for every file.
I using Queue and calling Download method recursively, one by one.

I tried summing all bytes that I need to download, and setting `progressBar.Maximum` to that value. But problem is how to keep progress bar updated with sum of all bytes downloaded.

```
private Queue<string> _downloadUrls = new Queue<string>();

private void downloadFile(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        _downloadUrls.Enqueue(url);
    }

    DownloadFile();
}

private void DownloadFile()
{
    if (_downloadUrls.Any())
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;

        var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();


        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), "C:\\Test4\\" + FileName);
        return;
    }

    // End of the download
    btnGetDownload.Text = "Download Complete";
}

private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // handle error scenario
        throw e.Error;
    }
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        // handle cancelled scenario
    }
    DownloadFile();
}

void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   progressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.BytesReceived);
}
```

Comment: Use `+=` instead of `=`

Comment: Sorry I will change now to code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Then I will be out of value before download. Because you're summing all bytes.

Comment: How do you compute the max value for the progress bar again? I'm assuming you can read the size of each file only when you start downloading it. In that case you can consider giving each file a set portion of the progress bar (say, 25% if you have 4 files), and then scaling the progress accordingly. Other option would be to scan the file sizes first and then start downloading.

Comment: Before I downloading I check size for each file. And sum them, then I start downloading one by one

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, sum all bytes and set that as the maximum. When a file has completed downloading, add it's size in bytes to field (e.g. `int _downloaded`). When download progress changes, set the progress to `_downloaded + e.BytesReceived` which is the total bytes received including past files.

Note you should reset `_downloaded` to 0 when you start downloading a list of files  again.